# Displaying elements of ObservableCollection in data grid columns

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a program where I am reading a .csv file with 2 columns, and my model has 2 properties.
I take instances of this model as the file is read and then add them to my ObvervableCollection.

Here is what it looks like:

```
// My data field
private ObservableCollection<Model> _internalFile = new ObservableCollection<Model>(); 

// My data accessor/setter
public ObservableCollection<Model> InternalFile { get { return _internalFile; } set { _internalFile = value; } }

Model x = new Model();

while (fileReader.Peek() != -1)
  {
    // words = read the line, split the line, make a list of columns
    var words = fileReader.ReadLine().Split(',').ToList();
    if (words[0] != "Name")
    {
     x.asWord = words[0];
     x.asNumber = int.Parse(words[1]);
     InternalFile.Add(x); 
     // InternalFile is a collection of 'Model' objects. 
     // So created 'Model' placeholder , x, and pile each instance of x 
     // in the collection to be displayed. 
    }
  }
```

My XAML looks like this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfMVVP.WindowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfMVVP"
    Title="Window View" Height="350" Width="525" Background="White">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InternalFile}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="As Word" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding asWord}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="As Number" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding asNumber}" />
         </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Status}" />
</Grid>
```

In the window displayed, I am seeing the columns populate but all the rows are the last row that was read before end of file.  It is as if the ObservableCollection is overwriting its previous elements with a new value. I don't know why it's behaving like that.

[image: Application Window]

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines(filename).Select(x => x.Split(',')).Select(x => new Model {Name = x[0], AsNumber = int.Parse(x[1]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only creating your `Model` once, and overwriting it each time w/ the last data read. What you want to do is create a new `Model` for each line read. You can simply move your `Model` instantiation inside your while loop. (see below)

```
// My data field
private ObservableCollection<Model> _internalFile = new ObservableCollection<Model>(); 

// My data accessor/setter
public ObservableCollection<Model> InternalFile { get { return _internalFile; } set { _internalFile = value; } }

while (fileReader.Peek() != -1)
  {
    Model x = new Model();
    // words = read the line, split the line, make a list of columns
    var words = fileReader.ReadLine().Split(',').ToList();

      if ((words[0] != "Name") && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(words[0]))
      {
        x.asWord = words[0];
        x.asNumber = int.Parse(words[1]);
        InternalFile.Add(x); 
        // InternalFile is a collection of 'Model' objects. 
        // So created 'Model' placeholder , x, and pile each instance of x 
        // in the collection to be displayed. 
      }
  }
```

Comment: That fixed it.  The data shows up in the grid fine.  I do however still have an extra row in the bottom which I don't know where it came from.

Comment: I believe that might be the CanUserAddRows property of the DataGrid. Try setting that to CanUserAddRows = false

Comment: @KaranveerPlaha Also, make sure there is not a newline (empty line) at the end of the document. See my update